# What are the seeds I can preserve and use in my terrace garden?

Tags: vegetables, seeds, germination, fruits, seed-saving

I have preserved haldi (turmeric) since December and planning to plant during this month. This has worked great last year. I will like to know what are the other seeds those I can get from day to day vegetables / Fruits those I should keep for a few months and can still germinate in Indian weather?

For e.g. Can I keep the per fruit seeds? Will they be useful if I have large open space?

Comment: Welcome! I am very sorry, but I have to close this question as too broad. As it stands, we could end up with an endless list of possible seeds that can be saved and which will (or will not) give you the results you expected. I encourage you to read [ask] and if you can, [edit] your post to make it answerable within the site’s scope and limits.

Answer (score 0):

I have started collecting my avocado pits. I'm not sure how long they keep, just don't let it dry out! They're a bit involved for growing from seed but here's a link describing the process:
https://www.californiaavocado.com/avocado101/your-own-avocado-tree